# Mozilla is not executing this code perfectly, although it works with Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

It is file validation code in JavaScript, which validates file being uploaded is of required format or not. While executing this code with Mozilla, Mozilla always displays "Not a valid file Extension" Error, whereas this script works with Chrome and IE perfectly.

```
regx_docx = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.doc|.docx|.DOC|.DOCX|.jpg|.jpeg|.JPG|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.bmp|.BMP|.png|.PNG|.pdf|.PDF|.xls|.XLS|.xlsx|.XLSX|.txt|.TXT|.rar|.RAR|.zip|.ZIP)$/;
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var field = fields[i];      
            if ((field.name == 'doc[]') && (field.value!= '')) {            
                if(!regx_docx.test(field.value)){
                    count++;
                    errtxt+= "\n"+count+") Not a valid file Extension.";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is it doing? Provide the desired and actual results please - making us guess at what your problem is makes it a lot harder to help you.

Comment: It is File Validation code in Javascript, which validates file being uploaded is of required format or not. while executing this code with mozilla  mozilla always displays "Not a valid file Extension" Error, Whereas this script works with Crome and IE perfectly.

Comment: U Can see its live working at following link  bit.ly/R9TdA6

Answer (score 2):

The part

```
^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+
```

is problematic in two ways:

1. it works on Windows only, since it assumes `\` as a path separator
2. It works only if the browser provides the path to the selected file, which Firefox doesn't (IE provides a dummy path) for security reasons

Since you're only interested in the extension anyway, just remove that part from your regex and you'll be fine.

Also, you need to escape the dot in order to make it match a literal `.` character.

```
regx_docx = /\.(doc|docx|DOC|DOCX|jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG|gif|GIF|bmp|BMP|png|PNG|pdf|PDF|xls|XLS|xlsx|XLSX|txt|TXT|rar|RAR|zip|ZIP)$/;
```